# XCode Server CI Bot Integrate error (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup a CI server on my Macbook, I have followed the documentation on the apple website up to the point of creating a bot and integrating my build. When I attempt to integrate the build I repeatedly get the following error:

```
Bot Issue: error. Build Service Error.
Issue: '/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/14a8ea2a72904f1abcecd38b1c02196b' exists and is not an empty directory (-4).
Integration Number: 13.
Integration URL: https://DavidMcQueens-MacBook-Pro-2.local/xcode/bots/BF817C9/integrations
Description: '/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/14a8ea2a72904f1abcecd38b1c02196b' exists and is not an empty directory (-4).
```

I have manually deleted the folders in this location, as well as changing the permissions incase the server was having issues writing. Each time I run, I receive the same error. Even after I have deleted the folder so it is empty before the integration.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this issue? I have built my iOS application in Swift (which I believe should still work with the CI server)

I am running OSX Server 4.0 and the latest version of XCode. 
I followed [Apple's documentation for creating bots](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/ConfigureBots/ConfigureBots.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH9-SW1)

Thanks,

**EDIT:**
After some experimenting and trying different things to see what the issue is, I disabled 2-factor authentication on my GitHub hosting. This appeared to solve the issue, despite the fact that I was generating a specific application key to get around 2-factor. It solved the issue for a small amount of time, and I managed to successfully get the bot to integrate a few times. However it appears to have gone back to its old tricks.

If anyone has any other knowledge on this, or has managed to get it working on their own machines it will be good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe I have solved this issue, the GitHub 2-factor authentication issue looks to be a red herring.
When setting up the bot, there is a section that says "Checkout the repository", I did not do this step because I already had the repository on my local machine and presumed that it would simply create the repository in another location, and server no other purpose.

However, after some investigation this step is very necessary. From what I understand, checking out the repository does create it again in another location, however this is necessary as this new repository is where the Bot's will pull changes into and build in order to perform the tests. I was trying to use the same repo for development and for the Bots, which it did not like.

Creating a clean checkout of the project (on the server), and configuring the bots in that project then allowed me to progress and get everything setup correctly. It comes down to user error. In hindsight, it makes perfect sense to have a separate repo for the bots (this is my first CI server setup), however the error messages were not helpful and I can't remember seeing this emphasised in the setup guide.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "create a new repo"? do you mean a new project, or do you mean a clean checkout of the project you're doing your integrations on?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Yes performing a checkout of the current repo/project to a separate location on the server. The server will use this repo to pull the changes into and build from. As I was setting up the server on my laptop, which is also my development machine, I didn't understand the need for another checkout location, which was the issue. I shall edit my answer to make it clearer.